# RStudio removing leading whitespace formatting from SQL

Tags: rstudio, code-formatting

I realize that this is technically a formatting rather than programming question, but it's inter-related to an understanding of both SQL and RStudio, so I feel it's still appropriate.

I have a script written in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that is very intricately formatted for ease of viewing. For example:

```
SELECT (
        CASE WHEN Variable in (1,2)
             THEN 1
             ELSE 2
             END
       )
```

However, when I paste this into RStudio, it becomes something like:

```
SELECT (
    CASE WHEN Variable in (1,2)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END
)
```

It maintains a tab when preceded by an open parenthesis, but nothing else. I can manipulate the size of the tabs it does keep, but no matter what options I use in Tools>GlobalOptions>CodeEditing, I can't keep any other formatting. It doesn't look like a big deal from the above example, but my code consists of multiple nested queries and becomes very confusing without the formatting. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured this out after asking the question, but I thought other people might have the same question, so I want to share the answer.

There's another option within Tools>GlobalOptions>CodeEditing that says "Auto-indent code after paste" that is checked as default. Apparently, it strips all your formatting AND adds its own tabs. Unchecking it fixed the problem.